# how to display edit input fields in lightbox using css3 in html5

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am new to html5 , on my layout I placed an "edit" button in a table row. When we click on edit button it displays particular row fields on light box with same layout. My problem is that when I click on edit button it should display particular row details in another window.

This is my table and edit button code in jsp:

```
<body onload="altRows();">
<%@include file="dbheader.jsp" %>
<table class="altrowstable" id="alternatecolor">
<tr>
<th>code</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Phone</th>
<th>Address1</th>
<th>Address2</th>
<th>Postal Code</th>
<th>E-mail</th>
<th>Website</th>
<th>Blog</th>
<th>Fax</th>
<th>City</th>
<th>State</th>
<th>Longitude</th>
<th>Latitude</th>
<th>Date</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach items="${businesslist}" var="business">
<tr>
<td>${business.busent_code}</td>
<td>${business.busent_name}</td>
<td>${business.busent_phone}</td> 
<td>${business.busent_address1}</td> 
<td>${business.busent_address2}</td> 
<td>${business.busent_postal_code}</td>
<td>${business.busent_email}</td>
<td>${business.busent_website}</td>
<td>${business.busent_blog}</td>
<td>${business.busent_fax}</td>
<td>${business.busent_city}</td>
<td>${business.busent_state}</td>
<td>${business. busent_longitude}</td>
<td>${business.busent_latitude}</td>
<td>${business.busent_date}</td>
<form:form commandName="business" action="updatebusinessess" method="post" >
<td> <form:input id="busent_name" path="busent_name" type="hidden"   value="${business.busent_name}"/>  
<input id="submit" type="button" onclick="javascript:return lightbox();" tabindex="5"value="Edit">
</form:form>
<td>Show Map</td>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
<table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" align="center">
<tr>   
<%--For displaying Previous link except for the 1st page --%>
<c:if test="${currentPage != 1}">
<td><a href="<c:url value="/business_details?page=${currentPage - 1}"/>">Previous</a></td>
</c:if>
<%--For displaying Page numbers.The when condition does not display a link for the current page-- %>
<c:forEach begin="1" end="${noOfPages}" var="i">
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${currentPage eq i}">
<td>${i}</td>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
<td><a href="<c:url value="/business_details?page=${i}"/>">${i}</a></td>
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
</c:forEach>
<%--For displaying Next link --%>
<c:if test="${currentPage lt noOfPages}">
<td><a href="<c:url value="/business_details?page=${currentPage + 1}"/>">Next</a></td>
</c:if>
</tr>
</table> <br><br>
<%@ include file="dbfooter.jsp" %>
```

this my lightbox and row fields code in jsp.

```
<div id="light1" class="content2">
<form:form commandName="business" action="savebusinessess" method="post"  runat="server">
<table border="0">
<c:forEach items="${businesslist}" var="business" >             
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<td><form:input  path="busent_name" value="${business.busent_name}" size="30"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Address1</th>
<td><form:input path="busent_address1" value="${business.busent_address1}" size="30"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Address2</th>
<td><form:input  path="busent_address2" value="${business.busent_address2}" size="30"/></td> 
</tr> 
<tr>
<th>City</th>
<td><form:input  path="busent_city" value="${business.busent_city}" size="30"/></td> 
</tr> 
<tr>
<th>State</th>
<td><form:input  path="busent_state" value="${business.busent_state}" size="30"/></td> 
</tr> 
<tr>
<th>Phone</th>
<td><form:input path="busent_phone" value="${business.busent_phone}" size="30"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Website</th>
<td><form:input  path="busent_website" value="${business.busent_website}" size="30"/></td> 
</tr>  
<tr>
<th>Zip code</th>
<td><form:input  path="busent_postal_code" value="${business.busent_postal_code}" size="30"/>       </td> 
</tr> 
<tr>
<th>Longitude</th>
<td><form:input path="busent_longitude" value="${business.busent_longitude}" size="30"/></td> 
</tr> 
<tr>
<th>Latitude</th>
<td><form:input  path="busent_latitude" value="${business.busent_latitude}" size="30"/></td> 
</tr> 
<tr>
<th>Date:</th>
<td><form:input  path="busent_date" value="${business.busent_date}" size="30"/></td> 
</tr>     
</c:forEach>            
</table>
<input id="submit" type="submit" align="left" value="update Details" onclick="myFunction();"/> 
</form:form>
<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light1').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none';">Close</a>
</div>
```

i am getting lightbox but i get all table rows display on lightbox.

controller:

```
@Controller
public class UpdateController {   
@Autowired
private UpdateService updateService;   
private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(UpdateController.class);
@RequestMapping(value = "/updatebusinessess")
public String updateBusinessess(Business business,Model model) {
logger.info("updatebusinessess");
List<Business> bus=updateService.updateBusinessdetails(business);
model.addAttribute("businesslist",bus);
model.addAttribute("business",new Business());
return "updatingdetails";
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/savebusinessess")
public String addBusinessess(Business business, BindingResult result) {
logger.info("addbusinessess");
updateService.saveBusinessdetails(business);
return "success";
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/update")
public String updateBusiness( Model model) {
logger.info("updatebusiness");
model.addAttribute("business",new Business());
return "updatebusinessdetails";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is that you should create a lightbox itself first to be in DOM. For example:

```
<div id="lightbox1">
    <input type="text" id="name1"/>
    <input type="text" id="address1"/>
    ...
</div>
```

Your button should fill its input with specific value. You can use also jQuery:

```
$("#name1").val("John");
$("#address1").val("My street 1");
...
```

I think the idea is clear now. If so, you need just take values from the row instead of "John" and "My street 1". The simplest way will be to name every component in rows for using in jQuery or you can find parent element for the every button on the row and relatively to that find particular inputs (this will be little challenging if you're new to HTML and JS).

For lightbox you can use any lightbox solution written in jQuery and attach the "div" element to that lightbox.

Comment: Thanks for your response that is not my problem i am getting lightbox but in lightbox all table rows are displayed  i need to display particular row details comes from database.

Comment: Do you need to get the data from database and display in lightbox?

Comment: Here you can see the sample http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_database_access.htm

Comment: I don't want code, in controller row details are submited it display on another window. but i need that details will come in lightbox.

Comment: Could you kindly provide full JSP code, screenshots and explain clearly what you want?

Comment: can you please tell me how to post screenshots.